# Почему этот рекурсивный счет работает?

Tags: php, рекурсия

В документации по `PHP` есть такой пример рекурсивного счета. Помогите разобраться, как он работает.

> Следующая простая функция рекурсивно считает до 10, используя для
> определения момента остановки статическую переменную `$count`:
>
> Пример #6 Статические переменные и рекурсивные функции
>
> ```
>  <?php
>  function test()
>  {
> static $count = 0;
>
> $count++;
> echo $count;
> if ($count < 10) {
>     test();
> }
> $count--;
> }
> ?>
> ```

Ну вызвала себя функция 1 раз, добавила к `$count` 1. Зачем отнимать 1 сразу же после функции? Там же опять `$count = 0` и получается бесконечная рекурсия? Или в момент вызова `test()` мы возвращаемся к началу функции, пропуская весь дальнейший код? Зачем тогда нам вообще `$count--;`?

Answer (score 0):

Вы не совсем поняли пример. Там статический count, он инициализируется один раз. Все остальные разы он только добавляет, а если учитывать, что от сначала только входит в ф-и, то отнимать он будет только на выходе из теста. Чтобы лучше понять, вынесите объявление статической переменной вне функции. Просто вычитание делается с расчетом, чтоб, когда ф-я закончила свою работу, значение переменной восстановилось в исходное значение.